# Desktop shortcut for sudo command

Tags: ideapad

I want to create a desktop shortcut to turn off conservation mode on my laptop. For that I need to run this command:
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
I made a desktop entry, but I don't know how to run it as superuser. This way it doesn't do anything.
The closest thing I found was pkexec but that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use an alias. In your /home/user directory there is a file called `.bashrc`.

Put this at the end of the file, leaving a blank line at the end.

```
alias name_of_alias='your_command_from_the_question_here'
```

Save the file then, from terminal, run `source .bashrc`.

Now you can use `name_of_alias` as a command freely.  Type it at command line, all by itself.  To use it in the desktop link you need to use: `bash -c "name_of_alias"`.

You do need `pkexec` to do it, if it doesn't want to pop up using `bash -c`, add it to the front of the command or try it with just the alias.

e.g. `pkexec name_of_alias`
or `pkexec bash -c name_of_alias`

One of them will surely work.

---

**Alternative to** `pkexec`/`alias`**:**
This not secure, and is not for production use!  It will keep the password visibly obfuscated and can be for personal use.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 your_commands_here"
    exit 1
fi

command="$1"

password=$(yad --title="SU Password" --skip-taskbar --window-icon="input-keyboard" --on-top --geometry="300x150" --borders=15 --image="input-keyboard" --text-align=center --text="Enter Password:" --entry --separator="" --item-separator="" --hide-text)

exit_code=$?

if [[ $exit_code -ne 0 ]]; then
  exit 1
fi

# Decode the base64-encoded password
decoded_password=$(echo "$password" | base64 -d)

# Execute the command with sudo and the decoded password
fld1=$(echo "$decoded_password" | sudo -S -p "" -k "$command")

exit 0
```

Save to: `yad_sudo.sh`
Change mode to executable: `chmod +x yad_sudo.sh`
Usage: `./yad_sudo.sh your_commands_here`

Use this for the shortcut:

```
bash -c /path/to/script/yad_sudo.sh echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Comment: I got the alias to work and I can run it from the terminal, but with pkexec it doesn't work. Just with pkexec my_alias it says: Cannot run program conv_off: No such file or directory
But with pkexec bash -c my_alias it says /usr/bin/bash: sor: 1: conv_off: command not found. Can you help with this?

Comment: I put your command in a shell script like [this](https://snippet.host/ujsqkz). Save it as `conserve_toggle.sh`  Run `chmod +x conserve_toggle.sh` Now use `pkexec bash -c /path/to/script/conserve_toggle.sh` for the shortcut.  If pkexec doesn't pop up, try `pkexec && bash -c...`

Answer (score -1):

Either configure your desktop icon to run the command in a terminal, so that sudo has somewhere to ask you for your password, or add an entry to the sudoers file to say that you can run the required command as root without a password.

A good way to debug this sort of thing is to add redirection of output (both stdout and stderr) into a file so that you can check it after you've tried the command. E.g.:

exec >/tmp/mylogfile 2>&1; set -x; ...

(You might need to put that whole script inside a bash -c option.)